# Resource usage increases abnormally in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

I am using GAE for my product development. Now it is MVP version and in development phase. So the user traffic is still small.

But today (14:00 27th Feb 2017 UTC+7) when I saw the statistics I cannot believe my eyes. So huge numbers of requests and bandwidth. I am attaching here:
**[Abnormal resource usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGT93.jpg)**

My request log and the App Engine Dashboard show the same traffic as usual (very small). So I think the Resource usage numbers is not correct.
**[Dashboard and Request log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLNEp.jpg)**

Please explain me where the huge number of requests come from?

Comment: did you check your datastore? seems to be that a lot of entities were created

Comment: Here is the Datastore screenshot: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img923/5461/CJn58C.jpg Everything seems normal. The Datastore last update is 25th Feb (2 days ago).

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484802/google-app-engine-increasing-in-datastore-operations

Comment: But why does the abnormal usage  occur just on February 27th? Today, the usage is stable again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I got from Google Cloud Support. I am sharing below, in case someone get the same problem as I had:

> The number of requests you see on your App Engine Dashboard is not 100% reliable as it sometimes reflect the only the projected usage not the exact usage. Your exact bill will only be reflected on your transaction history and it takes 24-48 hours for it to refresh to be able to display your usage for February 27, 2017. We can wait for 24-48 hours to validate that your transaction history will be the one to show your charges and usage.

[And here is the final resource usage statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4TLK.jpg)