# Google App Engine - increasing in Datastore operations

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

Today, we've been charged for the first time in Google App Engine, and the main cause seems to be Create, Read and Delete operations to the `Datastore`.

I'm trying to figure out what cause this - or talking about millions of operations which is weird.

We have half-daily task which delete 750 entities and write 750 new entities, so I believe its something we should take care of - but even then, how can it come to millions?

Another question is - if I'm using remote api, there is any extra affect on the `Datastore` operations?

We must reduce this number cause we are only 10-15 testing users and we cannot afford this costs at this point at all.

I'd like to hearing any suggestions from your experience, or thing we should check that may cause this operations.

Thanks

Comment: too broad to answer. spend more effort debugging. add traces then analize the log, show relevant code etc.

Comment: Note that the free quotas are not exactly in the 'millions', you only have 50k reads, 20k writes and 20k deletes per day for free.

Comment: did you read that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482420/resource-usage-increases-abnormally-in-google-app-engine?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer interesting.. I've already sent request to the GAE support for explanations.. I wish this is all one big mistake.

Comment: hi, please tell us the answer from GAE support. I checked my quotas and I can see the same what you described and I am the only one who is using my project :) Seems to be that is something wrong

Comment: ok, please check the following page https://status.cloud.google.com/?_ga=1.127713098.611368707.1483559980. you will find the following info "We are investigating reports of an issue with App Engine Quotas being higher than expected. App Engine apps might run into quota denials. We will provide more information by 11:30 US/Pacific."

Comment: @MichaelMeyer see that, thank you - can explain this mess.. 
About the support, they contacted me yesterday by phone and told me that my billings are OK (not charged) and that the technical support will check the high values on the dashboard too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be a composite index on list properties.

Imagine you have:

```
MyModel:
  Prop1: list of vals
  Prop2: list of vals
  Prop3: list of vals
```

and have a composite index on (Prop1,Prop2,Prop3).

If you push a single entity like `MyModel(prop1=[1,2,3], prop2=[4,5,6,7], prop2=[8,9,10,11,12])` it would produce:

```
2 write ops for key
3*2 write ops for props
3*4*5 write ops for composite index
=====================
Total of 68 write ops
```

With composite indexes on list properties you have write ops in geometrical progression and this can cause combinatorial explosion of index.

Comment: In my entire app there is not even one `List Property`. I can see massive changes in the App Engine dashboard (sometimes up and sometimes down)